# Replace nth line from the matched pattern

Tags: shell-script, shell, sed

I have following text file.

```
banana
apple
juice
mango
something
```

I am searching for pattern `juice`, and I want to find the 2nd line from that matching pattern in reverse order (i.e 2 lines above the matching pattern) and replace it with `coconut`.

Expected output:

```
coconut
apple
juice
mango
something
```

I tried with following, but it just deletes the above two line and not the exact one I'm looking for.

```
tac foo.txt |sed '/juice/I,+2 d' |tac
mango
something
```

I think tweaking above script would do the job, but I am not sure.

Note:
There will not be any re-occurrence of the match, and it needs not to be an exact match (meaning, the match can be found in a long line as well). The match should be case-sensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your approach,

```
tac file|sed '/juice/{n;n;s/.*/coconut/}'|tac
```

- `/juice/` matches a line with `juice`.
- `n;n;` prints the current and the next line.
- `s/.*/coconut/` makes the substitution.

Apparently you have GNU sed, so you could also use `-z` to get the whole file into memory and directly edit the line two above juice,

```
sed -rz 's/[^\n]*(\n[^\n]*\n[^\n]*juice)/coconut\1/' file
```

`[^\n]` means "not a newline" and the parenthesis `()` capture the group reproduced by the `\1` back-reference.

Answer (score 6):

If `ed` is okay, you need to edit a file,
not a stream, and there is only
one `juice`:

```sh
$ more <<-EOF | ed -s ./tmp.txt
	/juice/
	-2
	c
	coconut
	.
	w
	q
EOF
$
```

Find the line, go two lines up, `c`hange,
`w`rite, and `q`uit.

---

An even more compact variation, suggested
by @d-ben-knoble in the comments:

```sh
$ printf '%s\n' '/^juice$/-2s/.*/coconut/' w q | ed -s ./tmp.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ tac file | awk 'c&&!(--c){$0="coconut"} /juice/{c=2} 1' | tac
coconut
apple
juice
mango
something
```

Answer (score 2):

With bash, assuming your file is not large:

```bsh
mapfile -t lines < file
for (( i = 0; i < ${#lines[@]}; i++ )); do 
  if [[ ${lines[i]} == *"juice"* ]]; then
    lines[i-2]="coconut"
    break
  fi
done
printf '%s\n' "${lines[@]}"
```

If you would want case *insensitive* matching, add this before the loop:

```bsh
shopt -s nocasematch
```

---

With perl:

```bsh
perl -0777 -pe 's/^.*(?=\n.*\n.*juice)/coconut/m' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is yet another `awk` approach, this time a double-pass method:

```
awk 'NR==FNR&&/juice/{m=FNR} NR>FNR&&FNR==m-2{$0="coconut"} (NR>FNR)' file file
```

- We specify the file *two times* as command-line arguments, so that it gets processed twice.
- In the first pass (where `FNR`, the per-file line-counter, is equal to `NR`, the global line counter), we simply identify in which line the search pattern `juice` occurs, and store it in a variable `m`.
- In the second pass, we set line number `m-2` to the replacement text `coconut`.
- As a general rule, we print the lines including any modifications, but only in the second pass (where the condition `NR>FNR` evaluates to "true").

If you have GNU `awk` (some other `awk` implementations support this, too) you can speed up the process a little by aborting the first pass as soon as the match is found using the `nextfile` command:

```
awk 'NR==FNR&&/juice/{m=FNR;nextfile} NR>FNR&&FNR==m-2{$0="coconut"} (NR>FNR)' file file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **ex** line editor fir this task :

```
$ echo '/juice/-2s/.*/coconut/|x' | ex -s file

$ sed -Ee '
    1N;$!N
    s/.*(\n.*\n.*juice)/coconut\1/;t
    P;D
' file
```

PS : not in front of my terminal so they are untested for sintax and or some issues.